# Assertion failed TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to build a gradient boost classifier model using Tensor to predict an index value (could be 1/2/3/4) given 5 features. I tried to adapt the tutorial from Tensor but I don't find how to get pass through this error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [Labels must <= n_classes - 1] [Condition x <= y did not hold element-wise:x (head/ToFloat:0) = ] [[1][2][1]...] [y (head/assert_range/Const:0) = ] [1]
```

Here is the full traceback:

```
 [[node head/assert_range/assert_less_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert (defined at C:/Users/tanne/PycharmProjects/RFvsGBM/GBTF.py:60) ]]

D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:516: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:517: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:518: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:519: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:520: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:525: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:541: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:542: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:543: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:544: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:545: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:550: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
WARNING:tensorflow:Using temporary folder as model directory: C:\Users\tanne\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_h5rh9zw
WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\training_util.py:236: Variable.initialized_value (from tensorflow.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use Variable.read_value. Variables in 2.X are initialized automatically both in eager and graph (inside tf.defun) contexts.
WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\feature_column.py:2115: NumericColumn._transform_feature (from tensorflow.python.feature_column.feature_column_v2) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
The old _FeatureColumn APIs are being deprecated. Please use the new FeatureColumn APIs instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\canned\head.py:437: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_impl.py:180: add_dispatch_support.<locals>.wrapper (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.where in 2.0, which has the same broadcast rule as np.where
WARNING:tensorflow:Issue encountered when serializing resources.
Type is unsupported, or the types of the items don't match field type in CollectionDef. Note this is a warning and probably safe to ignore.
'_Resource' object has no attribute 'name'
2021-03-08 10:39:04.559721: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
WARNING:tensorflow:Issue encountered when serializing resources.
Type is unsupported, or the types of the items don't match field type in CollectionDef. Note this is a warning and probably safe to ignore.
'_Resource' object has no attribute 'name'
WARNING:tensorflow:Issue encountered when serializing resources.
Type is unsupported, or the types of the items don't match field type in CollectionDef. Note this is a warning and probably safe to ignore.
'_Resource' object has no attribute 'name'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1356, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1341, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1429, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [Labels must <= n_classes - 1] [Condition x <= y did not hold element-wise:x (head/ToFloat:0) = ] [[1][2][1]...] [y (head/assert_range/Const:0) = ] [1]
     [[{{node head/assert_range/assert_less_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert}}]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tanne/PycharmProjects/RFvsGBM/GBTF.py", line 60, in <module>
    est.train(train_input_fn, max_steps=100)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 367, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1158, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1192, in _train_model_default
    saving_listeners)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1484, in _train_with_estimator_spec
    _, loss = mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.train_op, estimator_spec.loss])
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 754, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1252, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1353, in run
    raise six.reraise(*original_exc_info)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1338, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1411, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1169, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 950, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1173, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1350, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1370, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [Labels must <= n_classes - 1] [Condition x <= y did not hold element-wise:x (head/ToFloat:0) = ] [[1][2][1]...] [y (head/assert_range/Const:0) = ] [1]
     [[node head/assert_range/assert_less_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert
```

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from IPython.core.display import clear_output
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
df = df.rename(columns={'Nitrogen Dioxide': 'ND', 'Sulphur dioxide': 'SD'})
df.pop("Month")
df.pop("GMT")

df['Index'] = df['Index'].apply(str)

dftrain, dfeval = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.3)

y_train = dftrain.pop('Index')
y_eval = dfeval.pop('Index')

vocabulary = y_train.unique()
vocab = []
for el in vocabulary:
    vocab.append(str(el))

NUMERIC_COLUMNS = ['ND', 'Ozone', 'PM10', 'PM2.5', 'SD']

feature_columns = []

for feature_name in NUMERIC_COLUMNS:
    feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(feature_name, dtype=tf.float32))

NUM_EXAMPLES = len(y_train)


def make_input_fn(X, y, n_epochs=None, shuffle=True):
    def input_fn():
        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(X), y))
        if shuffle:
            dataset = dataset.shuffle(NUM_EXAMPLES)
        # For training, cycle thru dataset as many times as need (n_epochs=None).
        dataset = dataset.repeat(n_epochs)
        # In memory training doesn't use batching.
        dataset = dataset.batch(NUM_EXAMPLES)
        return dataset
    return input_fn


# Training and evaluation input functions.
train_input_fn = make_input_fn(dftrain, y_train)
eval_input_fn = make_input_fn(dfeval, y_eval, shuffle=False, n_epochs=1)

params = {
  'n_trees': 50,
  'max_depth': 3,
  'n_batches_per_layer': 1,
  'center_bias': True
}

est = tf.estimator.BoostedTreesClassifier(feature_columns, **params, label_vocabulary=vocab)
# Train model.
est.train(train_input_fn, max_steps=100)

# Evaluation.
results = est.evaluate(eval_input_fn)
clear_output()
pd.Series(results).to_frame()
```

If someone have any idea how I could do ... Thank you

Comment: Can you please provide the full traceback?

Comment: Your labels must start from '0' rather from '1'

Comment: Yes I changed it, but nothing in the traceback changed

Comment: @Adrien_CH, Can you add `n_classes` parameter to your `tf.estimator.BoostedTreesClassifier` and try? It should be greater than the number of classifications your target has. Thanks!

Comment: I put the parameter to the classifier, set to 5, gave me this error: `raise ValueError('For now pruning is not supported with multi class.')
ValueError: For now pruning is not supported with multi class.`

Comment: Is it possible to share `test.csv` ? To replicate your issue, so that we can try to help you. Thanks!

Comment: Of course! Here's the csv file on OneDrive https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ai1gdZCLWvHwds3rIlw9q41vibw?e=yvDPrA